# Delete child from QDialog::layout

Tags: c++, qt, parent-child

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    public:
    MyDialog(QListWidget * w)
        : m_w(w)
    {
        m_layout = new QGridLayout(this);
        m_layout.addWidget( w );

        this->exec();
    } 

    ~MyDialog() {
        m_layout->removeWidget( m_w );
    }

    private:
    QGridLayout * m_layout;
    QListWidget * m_w;  
    }
```

w is also a child of the main's window layout. The problem is when an object of MyDialog is destroy, it destroy w too whereas it was remove in the MyDialog's destructor;

Have you got a better solution than clone the QListWidget w ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do smf like this:

```
~MyDialog()
{
   m_w.reparent(main_window);
}
```

But i think you doin smf wrog if you have to clone QListView.
Is't it easy to make context menu for QListView and run this dialog for specific QListViewItem?

Comment: Your solutions is partially working. I save the parent's m_w in and restore it with m_w.setParent(QWidget*). But after that, it isn't handle by the main's window layout. For the moment i'll clone the QListWidget (not QlistView as you tell), it's only a QList of pointer with a viewer.